# Controller changes does not reflect

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem. I tried to change the controller but when I open the route it doesn't reflect with the latest controller? Any idea?

**Controller**

```
public function indexApplication(){
   return "testing";
}
```

**Api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/claim'], function(){
   Route::get('/test', ['as' => 'claim.test', 'uses' => 'ClaimController@indexApplication']);
}
```

**Response from rest client**

[image: Response from Rest Client]

Comment: change `*` before ClaimController to `'`

Comment: Route::get('/test', ['as' => 'claim.test', 'uses' => 'ClaimController@indexApplication']

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo in the questions. It still doesn't work.